# Find rows only present in the result of one of two queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two JOIN queries which give an output column of `Id`. How do I find all the `Id` values returned by query 1 but not returned by query 2?

```
select Id from Table1 join Table2;

select Id from Table2 join Table3;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT id FROM dbo.Table1 INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 ON ...
EXCEPT
SELECT id FROM dbo.Table2 INNER JOIN dbo.Table3 ON ...;
```

Comment: Awesome answer with the 'except'--I had never seen that before!

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
select Id from Table1 join Table2
union
select Id from Table2 join Table3
```